# How can I give path to a particular folder and just run the cypress specs in that folder using an npm script

Tags: node.js, cypress

In my cypress test, I have tests written in `desktop` and `mobile` folders under the integration folder. When I am running the `npm run cy:mobile-atp` from the Git bash cli, it is running all the cypress spec files from the desktop folder as well. How can I run just the spec related to the mobile alone ?

```
  "scripts": {
        "cy:run": "cypress run",
        "cy:desktop-atp": "set CYPRESS_RETRIES=2 && cypress run --record --key <some record key> --spec cypress/integration/desktop/**/*",
        "cy:mobile-atp":"node integration-tests.js --mobile --record --key <some record key> --spec cypress/integration/mobile/**/*"
      },
```

Comment: There are a couple of suggestions here [cypress run --spec cypress/integration/APP/**/* runs all tests instead of just subfolder APP tests](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1845). First is to use a trailing comma, I suppose `--spec cypress/integration/desktop/**/*, "`. Second is to wrap the glob in single quotes which would be `--spec 'cypress/integration/desktop/**/*' "`.